# 501 on PUT request

Tags: node.js, http, https, http-headers

We have a UI code that calls our backend to do a GET and PUT using https protocol.
(i.e. GET /api/data  and PUT /api/data)
On the backend side, we have handlers defined for both GET and PUT for this path.
Somehow GET works fine, but for PUT we are getting 501 back.

One thing to note is that we did set Akamai for this app.
Before, the Akamai, I think it was working fine when UI was talking directly using the host.
But now using this public host from Akamai, PUT doesn't seem to work as it did before.

Initially, I saw this:
[image]

And decided to add this:
res.setHeader('Referrer-Policy', 'same-origin');

Now I am seeing this:
[image]

Any idea what might be going on or what I might need to set so that both GET and PUT works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue before. Most likely you have a Web.Config or something similar that is blocking PUT requests.

For example in some PHP based backends in Azure I had to add: (there was only GET, POST and therefore the other requests were blocked)

```
<handlers>
  <add name="PHP73_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Turns out to be Akamai setting issue.
Only GET and POST was getting enabled by default using some script we were using, but not PUT and that was causing 501 for the PUT.
Thank you.